# Reactjs form calculation data working only for inputs

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to perform realtime calculations for form inputs, checkbox, select etc via **Reactjs**.

A good example of what am trying to implement can be found in this **fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/flamedenise/fpovk96p/

The Code below works fine only for form input real-time data entry calculation.
 My problem is that the select and checkbox
is not working when their corresponding values are selected or checked respectively. can someone help me fix that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label id="rootsearch"></label>
    <script type="text/babel">

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 this.state = {value: '', first: '', second: '', third: '', fourth: ''};

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
this.onKeyPressed = this.onKeyPressed.bind(this);
  }



   handleChange1(e) {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
   }

 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

onKeyPressed(e) {
  console.log(e.key);
//alert('you click me');
//var first = parseFloat(this.state.first);

// convert it to a float
var first = Number(this.state.first);
var second = Number(this.state.second);
var third = Number(this.state.third);
var fourth = Number(this.state.fourth);
var total_expenses = first + second + third + fourth;

this.setState({
total_expenses_due: total_expenses,
});

}

  componentDidMount() {
  }




render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
<select  onKeyUp={(e) => this.onKeyPressed(e)}  value={this.state.first}  onChange={this.handleChange1}>
            <option value="">-select-</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>

          </select><br />




<input type="checkbox" onKeyUp={(e) => this.onKeyPressed(e)}  value={this.state.second} onChange={this.handleChange1} name="second"   placeholder="Plane Ticket..." /> 20 <br />

<input  onKeyUp={(e) => this.onKeyPressed(e)} value={this.state.third} onChange={this.handleChange1} name="third" placeholder="Hotel Expenses..."  /><br />
<input  onKeyUp={(e) => this.onKeyPressed(e)} value={this.state.fourth} onChange={this.handleChange1} name="fourth" placeholder="Eating Expenses..." /><br />
<br /><br />
Total: {this.state.total_expenses_due}
<br />
Total: <input  type="text" value={this.state.total_expenses_due} onChange={this.handleChange1} placeholder="Total Expenses..."/>




                </label>

      </span>
   );    
}



}
ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('rootsearch')
);


 </script>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Checkbox value would be either true or false .how it is going to pick 20 as a value and in Select box there is no attribute of 'name'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need 2 methods to handle your all inputs, 1 for the total expenses and 1 for others, also remove the total expense change method if you do not want it.

like this

```
  handleChange(e) {
    let value = e.target.value;
    if (e.target.name === 'second') {
      value = 20;
    }
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: value }, function () {
      var first = Number(this.state.first);
      var second = Number(this.state.second);
      var third = Number(this.state.third);
      var fourth = Number(this.state.fourth);
      var total_expenses = first + second + third + fourth;
      this.setState({ total_expenses_due: total_expenses });
    });    

  }

  handleTotalexpenses(e) {
    var first = Number(this.state.first);
    var second = Number(this.state.second);
    var third = Number(this.state.third);
    var fourth = Number(this.state.fourth);
    var total_expenses = first + second + third + fourth;
    this.setState({ total_expenses_due: e.target.value });
  }
```

You do not need keypress or anything else to handle as you already dealing with names,
your names are missing in select and checkboxes.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ozagrf)

Comment: Thanks Sir Just Code. Your solution is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I never knew that the issue was just simple. Thanks to Ashish Sherawat. Setting the name attribute in the select and initializing the check box value in the state within the constructor solve the issue. Thanks to Ashish Sherawat